# Hibernate null pointer(session) when having a lot of mapping classes

Tags: hibernate, nullpointerexception

When I'm inserting an object with a generic DAO class im getting null pointer in session, that **happen only when I have a lot of mapping classes**  (I have 110 tables in db), if I do the same test with exactly **same code but only with 10 mapping classes in the package mappings/hibernate.cfg the program works correctly**, it looks like DAO tries to go faster than hibernate session loading? (It's perfonmance problem?)
Thanks in advance I'm wasting so much time to solve this.

This is my hibernate session:

```
public class HibernateSession {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory= buildSessionFactory();
    private static Session session;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        if (null == session || !session.isOpen()) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        }
        return session;
    }

}
```

insert method:

```
public void insert(T entity) throws HibernateException {
    try {
        startTransaction();
        session.persist(entity);
        session.flush();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        handleException(e);
    } finally {
        endTransaction();
    }
}

protected void startTransaction() {

    session = HibernateSession.getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
}

    protected void endTransaction() {
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Console:

```
    abr 25, 2016 10:52:59 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
abr 25, 2016 10:53:00 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tws.hibernate.dao.GenericDAO.endTransaction(GenericDAO.java:58)
    at tws.hibernate.dao.GenericDAO.insert(GenericDAO.java:87)
    at TwsTestRunner.main(TwsTestRunner.java:26)
```

Comment: What does the `GenericDAO` do? Post the code of the line(s) where the NPE happens.

Comment: Your stacktrace tells a different story - the problem is an NPE in `GenericDAO`'s endTransaction method. The `finally` block gets called despite the Exception and fails to find the transaction.

Comment: the original code is 
`
 protected void endTransaction() {
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  session.close();
 }
`
I edited it to make it more readable, I will put the original to avoid future confusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it, it was a different exception, but was not showing in console, I could see the error doing an instance of HibernateSession at the start of the program, the error was :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Mixing nullable and non nullable columns in a property is not allowed:
```

**It was a problem of the database, some FK wherent marked as not nullable so hibernate was mapping them wrong.**, the program worked when I had few tables because they were correct.